# can i loop php SELECT name with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, select

I'm looping php to select names..

```
$a = 1;
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2))
echo "<tr><td>".$row2['subject_name']."</td>
<td align='center'><select  name='ST".$a."'>
```

So it iterates `ST1`, `ST2` ....

Now I want to access the values of those selects in javascript. Can I rewrite the following code using loop?

```
T[1] = frm.ST1.value;
T[2] = frm.ST2.value;
....
T[12] = frm.ST12.value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but should work:

```
for (var i = 1; i<=12; i++){
    T[i] = frm['ST'+i].value;
}
```

Thiscode basically uses the fact that in javascript youoften can access `object.member` as `object[member]`. My intuition tells me it's always true, but I'm kind of not sure about that.

**Update:** [quirksmode.org article "Objects as associative arrays"](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) says that it's always true, so you can cbet on it.